# Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings

Tags: facebook, jsp

I am trying to integrate **Facebook** login button in my application:
App id configuration done :

Appdomain: localhost
Site URL:

> ```
>   http://localhost:8080/
> ```

This is the URL i am trying to access.

> ```
>   http:// localhost:8080/EBankingWeb/
> ```

It works fine for above URL. But doesnt work for my central Application URL

> ```
>   http:// blp4ux13:13542/corp/
> ```

What changes i need to do for above URL to work as well.

Below is the error i am getting on click of facebook login button:

**Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, orthe domain must be subdomain of one of the App's domain**

Answer (score 1):

The server where you host your app must match the app domain you configured, simple as that. Check your settings for your app at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).